# Javascript event driven XML parser (SAX ?)

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have use XSLT to transform my XMLs to plain HTML for sometime ...
...but I started to add more and more JS in the resulting HTML, and now it is just a bunch of JSON and display:none HTML tags.

At that point, I'm reconsidering my initial XSLT choice.

I was thinking of something more event oriented like SAX : parse the XML and trigger JS code that build my JS model.

Is there a native JS api to do that ?
Note that I'm very happy with XSLT and if I can just execute JS instead of writing to html output, I can reuse my XSLT code with almost no changes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Native JS API" in which context? Mozilla had that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/SAX but I think it was only available extensions, not to client-side script.

Comment: Context would be browser client side script (currently my app is working only in Firefox because of local file access restriction in Chrome).

Comment: I have never used SAX with Javascript but a simple web search turns up stuff like http://debeissat.nicolas.free.fr/sax.php or https://www.npmjs.com/package/sax

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of SAX parsers for Javascript that I'm aware of (I don't know what you mean by "native"). We've been using one from github/isaacs/sax-js which seems to do a reasonable job.

Alternatively, take a look at Saxon-JS, which is an XSLT 3.0 processor written in Javascript which allows you to invoke Javascript from your XSLT (and also to process user input events in XSLT, if that's of interest).